# how to run open -n applicaton name from command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I got these two lines that I want to run from a script file (on Yosemite 10.10.3). It works when running from terminal

```
CX_LICENSE=LS
open -n /Applications/Inspire\ Designer\ 10.0\ GA/Inspire\ Designer.app/
```

I saved these two lines in a file and named it run ID. -rwxr-xr-x@  1 Administrator  staff         89 20 Jul 17:34 runID

If I double click runID then I get new window with

```
Last login: Mon Jul 20 17:22:27 on ttys002
dsa-mac1:~ Administrator$ /Users/Administrator/Desktop/runID ; exit;
: command not foundr/Desktop/runID: line 1: 
/Users/Administrator/Desktop/runID: line 1: -n: command not found
logout

[Process completed]
```

any idea how to make runID work?

Comment: yes, it's correct. Copied from terminal.

Comment: I used standard text editor. Cannot remember its name right now.

Comment: I am not able to do that right now. I was doing remote session and trying to solve an issue. I'll ask someone to issue and see. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The error message doesn't seem to match your code sample (-n is on line 2), but this may be the result of having Windows-stil end of lines. Can you use `nano` as an editor, write the script there and try again?

Comment: Also, to use a specific application, you'll need the `-a` option like `open -n -a "Inspire Designer.app"`.

Comment: I used OSX native editor to create and edit the script. I think it's called TextEdit. Unfortunatelly I am not able to access this OSX computer anymore :-( Why do I have to use `-a` option as the command line version works fine?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the initial line of your script file - the "shebang".

Put the following in your script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
CX_LICENSE=LS
open -n /Applications/Inspire\ Designer\ 10.0\ GA/Inspire\ Designer.app/
```

That should work - the file you had before did not have enough information to tell the operating system *how* to run your script. You want to run a set of shell commands, so you need to tell the operating system it's a shell script, which is done by including the `#!/bin/sh` as the first line of the script.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7366796/292095) on Stack Overflow for more information.

**Update**

Just to confirm, I've just tested this script and it works fine:

```
#!/bin/sh
open -n /Custom\ Applications/MacVim.app
```

As correctly pointed out by @fd0, you should name the script `<script>.tool` or `<script>.command` for it to be executed from Finder (where `<script>` is a meaningful name for the script).

Comment: I think I tried that already. Let me confirm tomorrow.

Comment: Yep, I tried before posting this question. Getting this "dsa-mac1:Desktop Administrator$ ./runID 
./runID: line 2: -n: command not found"

Comment: I've just tested using a similar script and it works a charm - see my updated answer.

Comment: @mjturner - Shell scripts aren't meant to be double clickable unless suffixed with `.command` or `.tool`. In either case the text files do not need a shebang. The script runs within an instance of the user's shell.

Comment: @fd0 Yes, so I've realised (and thanks for the `.command`/`.tool` tip). Also, I neglected to test using Finder :(